# Proof of Quotient Rule Using Sigma Notation

Tags: calculus

> [image]

For this exercise I believe that I am essentially being write to prove the quotient rule using sigma notation. I can prove this rule easily enough using the definition of the derivative, but how would I relate to product rule to this kind of notation? Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: The question does not seem to ask you to *prove* the product rule or the quotient rule. It seems to only check if you understand both sigma notation and the quotient rule well enough to combine them into one expression--no proof needed. (Note that I said the *quotient* rule, not the *product* rule, though there will be a couple of products in the answer. You probably are to write those products out to have a "simple" polynomial in the numerator.)

Comment: Thanks @RoryDaulton. I did mean to say the quotient rule instead of the product rule, that was my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.**  Use the fact that

$$
P' \equiv \frac{dP}{dx} = \sum_{k=0}^n ka_kx^{k-1} = \sum_{k=1}^n ka_kx^{k-1}
$$

and similarly for $Q' \equiv dQ/dx$, and then

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \frac{P}{Q} = \frac{P'Q-Q'P}{Q^2}
$$